# Wordpress Error : You must log in to access the admin area

Tags: wordpress, passwords

I have entered the credentails and it logged me in.
I can login but on updating any page it gives error that You must log in to access the admin area.
Kindly let me know what should I do.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done.
It was issue of plugins that need to be updated.